# Is it compatible with the same meaning ?? Each country's perception / perception of each country

Tags: meaning, nuance, context

As far as I know the meaning of "perception of people" is "perception about people"

but when I want to say "people's perception, can I also change it to "perception of people" form with the same meaning??

Though "perception of people" means "perception about people", can I also use it to say "people's perception" depending on the context?

Depending on the context, are those interchangeable ??

perception of people = perception about people //
perception of people = people's perception

Comment: Regarding the title: each takes a singular noun, so it should be *each country's perception* and *the perception of each country.*

Answer (score -1):

Yes, *if* the context is clearly "a people's perception of other people." But it's hard to say for sure without a better idea of what the actual context is. Generally speaking, without any additional information to go on, it probably wouldn't be understood as such.

Comment: Thanks first. Assuming that I need to make the title of some seminar, "perception and future perspective of each country on the Ocean" would be Ok for that making the proper context ??

Comment: @Sam If you made "perception" and "perspective" plural, and changed "of" to something like "between," I think it would be more clear what you mean. I would suggest "Perceptions and Future Perspectives Between Countries on the Ocean."

Comment: If I use "between", doesn't it imply that there are just two countries for the issue? But if there are more than two, do I have to use "among"??

Comment: @Sam Whoops. "Between" can be used [with more than two](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/between-versus-among), as well, but not in this case, since the items are not distinct (sorry, it's very late here! Lol). So, yes, definitely use "among" since that *always* means more than two. Good catch.

Comment: @Sam Another suggestion I'd make might be to write something like, "Current and Future Perceptions Among Countries on the Ocean." That sounds a little more clear to me, as well. (No pun intended.)

Comment: Wait, are we talking about the perceptions of the countries (which are on the ocean) _about each other_, or the perceptions of the countries _about the ocean_? I assumed the latter, but all the comments seem to assume the former. Which just goes to show that it's a bad title!